# parsing a text file with particular keyword matching

Tags: c, file, io

I need to create a search program in C language, that can parse the text file and find the keyword x="value". then I want to create a list of value items into array. Currently I am using fscanf approach, here is my code snippet.

```
    fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);
    if !strcmp(buf, "x")
    {
       fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);
        if ( ! strcmp(buf, "="))
         fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);
        else
        printf("\n Not a valid format");
    }
```

I don't want to use fscanf, Is there any other approach for my requirement??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other approaches (e.g., you could use Flex), but I think slightly better use of `sscanf` would make the most sense:

```
char buffer[256];
char value[128];

fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);

if (1==sscanf(buffer, "x=%127s", value))
     // we read a value -- now use it however needed.
```

Edit: The basic idea here is pretty simple. We start by reading a whole like with `fgets`. We then use `sscanf` to try to match `x=<whatever>` in that line. If we find it, we have the value we care about. If we didn't find it, sscanf will return 0, since it returns the number of items it converted -- and if it doesn't match the `x=` we specified, it won't convert anything, so sscanf will return 0, and we know that line didn't match.

Edit 2: Here's a small demo program that reads data from a file, and prints out the values for lines that follow the form `x=<whatever>`, with spaces allowed before and after the `x` and the `=`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 

    FILE *infile = fopen("Somefile.txt", "r");

    char buffer[256];
    char value[128];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), infile))
        if (1 == sscanf(buffer, " x = %127s", value))
            printf("Value = %s\n", value);
    return 0;
}
```

I tested it with this as input:

```
some junk
#a comment
a = 1 ; a couple other variables.
b = 2
x = 3
 x = 4
x=5
```

The result I got was:

```
Value = 3
Value = 4
Value = 5
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, can you please describe your answer in detail?

Comment: Good. but, Is it good to store file data into buffer? can you please provide me above example with file operation?? thanks a lot.

Comment: I would suggest having space around the `=` in the format string, like this: `"x = %127s"`. This will allow the user to have space around the `=` as well in the file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Could be -- I was just trying to parse the format he said he expected. If you wanted to allow spaces, `" x =%127s"` would make more sense -- allow space before the "x". %s will skip leading white-space automatically.

Comment: @Nimit: For a case like this, it's usually cleanest/easiest to read a line at a time. This way, if the line wasn't formatted correctly, you just read the next line. Otherwise, you need to add some code to read and discard the remainder of the line after your conversion failed.

Comment: @Nimit: It's the same as %s, but limited to reading a string no more than 127 characters long.

Comment: @jerry: Thanks a lot. It's only retrieve the x=value, which begins from the line, means if i am adding x=value after space(or tab) in text file then it don't consider it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I am having trouble with your solution, In your example if the value of x contain any white space then it's not allowed whole string, means if value of x is "Hi Jerry", then it only parse "Hi". Could you please suggest me any solution for it?